# How do I create a number of objects with insertMany with existing data from the db?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm currently trying to insert a large number of models through insertMany, but I can't seem to figure out how to populate the array when creating an object. I'm relatively new to Mongoose and any help would be appreciated, here is the code I have right now.

```
const ProgramsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   program_id: {
       type: String,
       required: true
   },
   description: {
       type: String
   },
});
```

```
const schoolsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    inst_url: {
        type: String
    },
    programs: {
        type: [{type: ProgramsSchema, ref: "Programs"}]
    }
});
```

And here's the code where I try to create a number of schools and add it to the database.

```
let new_schools = []
for (let i = 0; i < schools.length; i++) {
  let school = schools[i]
  let p_arr = []
  for (let p_index = 0; p_index < school["PROGRAMS"].length; p_index++) {
     let p_id = school["PROGRAMS"][p_index]
      Programs.find({program_id: p_id}).populate('Programs').exec(function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        p_arr.push(data[0])
      }
    })
  }
  let newSchool = {
    inst_url: school["INSTURL"],
    programs: p_arr,
  }
  new_schools.push(newSchool);
}

Schools.insertMany(new_schools);
```

I can basically add all of the school data into the db, but none of the programs are being populated. I was wondering if there was a way to do this and what the best practice was. Please let me know if you guys need more info or if my question wasn't clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with your mongoose schemas. The operation you are trying to do in `find` is not available, based on your mongoose schemas. You cannot populate from "Programs" to "Schools". You can populate from "Schools" to "Programs", for instance:

```js
Schools.find().populate(programs)
```

And to do that, several changes in your schemas are necessary. The idea is to store the programs `_id` in your `programs` array in School collection and be able to  get the programs info through `populate()`, either regular populate or 'custom populate' (populate virtuals).

### Regular `populate()`

I would change the `schoolsSchema` in order to store an array of `_id` into `programs`:

```js
const schoolsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    inst_url: {
        type: String
    },
    programs: [
        {type: String, ref: "Programs"}
    ]
});
```

You should change `ProgramsSchema` as well:

```js
const ProgramsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId, // that's important
   description: {
       type: String
   },
});
```

And now, you can do:

```js
Programs.find({_id: p_id}).exec(function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        p_arr.push(data[0]._id)
    }
})
```

Your documents should be inserted correctly. And now you can populate `programs` when you are performing a query over `School`, as I indicated above:

```js
Schools.find().populate(programs)
```

### Populate Virtual

The another way. First of all, I have never tried this way, but I think it works as follows:

If you want to populate over fields that are not `ObjectId`, you can use populate virtuals (https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate-virtuals). In that case, your schemas should be:

```js
const ProgramsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   program_id: String,
   description: {
       type: String
   },
});
const schoolsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    inst_url: {
        type: String
    },
    programs: [
        {type: String, ref: "Programs"}
    ]
});
```

Enable virtual in your School schema:

```js
Schools.virtual('programs', {
  ref: 'Programs',
  localField: 'programs',
  foreignField: 'program_id'
});
```

Then, you should store the `program_id`.

```js
Programs.find({program_id: p_id}).exec(function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        p_arr.push(data[0].program_id)
    }
})
```

And as before, you can `populate()` when you need.

I hope I helped